# JS can't add class to an element in React template

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap template that I'm using for a React app. Inside the template, there's this piece of JS that's supposed to make the header sticky on scroll. It works in pure HTML, but when I move the header to a React template (which is necessary because React handles i18n), then adding a class this way no longer works. What's the simplest workaround here?

```
 let selectHeader = select('#header')
  if (selectHeader) {
    let headerOffset = selectHeader.offsetTop
    let nextElement = selectHeader.nextElementSibling
    const headerFixed = () => {
      if ((headerOffset - window.scrollY) <= 0) {
        selectHeader.classList.add('fixed-top')
        nextElement.classList.add('scrolled-offset')
      } else {
        selectHeader.classList.remove('fixed-top')
        nextElement.classList.remove('scrolled-offset')
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', headerFixed)
    onscroll(document, headerFixed)
  }
```

I've tried using jQuery, hasn't worked either.

Comment: Generally mixing React with DOM manipulation is a bad idea, ideally you'd let React add/remove the class itself when rendering the header component.

Comment: Direct DOM interaction is usually the wrong approach in React.  Is the component re-rendering after you apply these changes, effectively removing the changes?  What is this `select` function being called?  Or `onscroll`?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't _need_ React for i18n. Can you point to something that says it's a requirement?

Comment: @Andy The employer requires it to be done with React.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript to make a header sticky. You can use the `position: sticky` CSS rule.

A React example.

```js
const { Fragment } = React;

function Example() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <header className="header">Header</header>
      <main className="main">Main</main>
    </Fragment>
  );

}

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.header { position: sticky; top: 0; background-color: lightgray; height: 25px; padding: 0.25rem;}
main { height: 2000px; padding: 0.25rem;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't solve the problem either as I need the header to change the appearance when the page is scrolled down.

Comment: Hi @PJK. It solves the problem you presented in your question. Your question doesn't explicitly mention anything about changing its appearance. How is it meant to change?

Comment: Note: at some point [scroll-driven animations](https://scroll-driven-animations.style) will come to a browser near you. See the example on "Shrinking Header + Shadow" in Chrome 115.